# App is Ready For Sale and beta testing rejection notification is still showing

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, beta-testing

I have created one application. Then I have uploaded app on the store and set it for `Beta testing` on `TestFlight`.

After that `Apple` rejected app because of wrong credentials I have provided to login into app.

Then I have made some changes in UI and features and then decided to test app manually.
So I have tested app with my friends and colleagues.

After that I have uploaded app on `itunesconnect` for making live to user and not on `TestFlight` (No need to test now).

Now app is live on the store `Ready For Sale`, but still it is showing red notification for beta testing rejection on the app icon.

How to remove that ?

Here are screenshots, I have added :

[image]
[image]

Comment: you can check build number or version? it's Same?

Comment: Either ignore it or submit your new build for external TestFlight testing